# Blazor HTML Link is hidden until mouseover

Tags: html, url, anchor, blazor

In Blazor razor page if I place an HTML anchor such as
`<a href="http://example.com">My Text</a>`
the text doesn't show until the mouse is moved over it.
I have worked around this by making it a Button.
Is there any solution to this or or better linkage component to use?

Comment: change the css style for `a` color

Comment: You can open browser inspector and check what CSS is causing this misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this in a new project.

The behaviour seems to suggest this might be a CSS problem. To confirm this, try giving your `a` an `id` and set a specific style

```
#tester {
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Then

```
<a id="tester" href="http://example.com">My Text</a>
```

When you run the app you should now hopefully see the link. Right-click it, and select "Inspect Element", then look down the CSS rules for that element for anything that has a strike-through font (meaning it has been overridden by a more specific rule).

One of these should be something hiding your element. Once you've found the culprit, kill it :)